# How to use the value of <select> in with django function?

Tags: javascript, python, django

So I want to make a function with if in my html using django.

My function looks like :

```
function try() {document.getElementById("demo").inerHTML = '{%for x in xl%}'+
'{%if x.name == document.getElementById("select1").value%}'+
'<button type="button">hello</button>'+
'{%endif%}{%endfor%}'}
```

And the relevant html is :

```
<select id="select1">
<option value = "tiger"></option>
<option value = "bear"></option>
<option value = "eagle"></option>
</select>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>try();</script>
```

So just to make it clear :
'xl' is a list, the items in this list have a name variable.
I want my web to show in the "demo" paragraph 'hello' buttons for each time that the selcted animal is the name of item in the list.

When trying to run this it says : " Could not parse the remainder: '("select1").value;' from 'document.getElementById("select1").value;' "

Please help me find what`s wrong and how to fix it, Thanks.

Comment: What? What are you possibly trying to do here? You seem to be mixing up JS and Django template syntax in a very odd way that can't ever work.

Comment: I explained what I'm trying and and im probably doing something wrong. If you have any idea how to do it right please help.

Comment: Daniel is correct. There is no way conceivable this is going to work. You can certainly output server-side Django variables in JavaScript code, but I have no idea why you're not just using a Django form and then outputting the selected option via JavaScript.

Comment: @Brandon Can you show me how use that form that your`e talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a Django form, and then get the selected option value with JavaScript? Example code has *not* been tested. You still need an app within your Django project, settings, templating, routing, etc.

```
# forms.py
class AnimalForm(forms.Form):
    TIGER = 'Tiger';
    BEAR = 'Bear'
    EAGLE = 'Eagle'
    ANIMAL_CHOICES = (
        (TIGER, TIGER,),
        (BEAR, BEAR,),
        (EAGLE, EAGLE,),
    )

    animal = forms.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ANIMAL_CHOICES,
        default=TIGER)

    def save(self):
        return NotImplementedError
        # implement

# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import AnimalForm


def choose_animal(request):

    form = AnimalForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        # do something, like redirect to a success page, etc

    return render(request, 'animal_form.html',
        {'form': form})


#animal_form.html

<form action="." method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    {{ form.animal }}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
<p id="animal-selection"></p>

<script>
    // assuming jQuery is already linked for brevity

    (function($) {
        $(function() {
            $('#id_animal').on('change', function() {
                $('#animal-selection').html($(this).val());
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```